# spring batch custom jdbc itemreader

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

i want to create a custom jdbc itemreader i found this solution

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseToXmlFileJobConfig {

private static final String QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS =
        "SELECT " +
            "email_address, " +
            "name, " +
            "purchased_package " +
        "FROM STUDENTS " +
        "ORDER BY email_address ASC";

@Bean
ItemReader<StudentDTO> databaseXmlItemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<StudentDTO> databaseReader = new 
JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql(QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS);
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>
(StudentDTO.class));

    return databaseReader;
}
}
```

but i don't know how to use it , to create my own ItemReader ?
is there anyway to make link between this two classes ?
or anyway to create a custom JDBC reader?

```
public class DatabaseReader implements ItemReader<StudentDTO> {

@Override
public StudentDTO read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, 
ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: okey sorry ^^ , it was genereted automatically

Comment: Oh... I see. Stack Overflow generate tags randomly.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring batch there are 3 core elements for an step

1. Reader
2. Processor (optional)
3. Writer

Spring batch already provides a set of [readers and writers](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/appendix.html#listOfReadersAndWriters) for most common cases, if you don't have an special scenario you can use them right out of the box

From what I can see at your question you could use it as it is.

Job

```
    @Bean
    public Job jobTest(){
        JobParametersBuilder parametersBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        Instant timestamp =LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();

        return jobBuilder.get("myJobName")
                .next(StudentsReport())
                .next(sendReportByEmail())
                .incrementer( jobParameters -> parametersBuilder.addJobParameters(jobParameters)
                                                                .addDate("timeStamp"
                                                                        , Date.from( timestamp)
                                                                 ).toJobParameters()
                )
                .build();
    }
```

Step Definition

```
    @Bean
    public Step studentsReport(){
        return stepBuilder.get("getStudentsThatSomething")
                .<User,User>chunk(100)
                .reader(studentsJdbcReader())
                .writer(studentsXMLWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

JDBC Reader Bean

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

private static final String QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS =
        "SELECT " +
            "email_address, " +
            "name, " +
            "purchased_package " +
        "FROM STUDENTS " +
        "ORDER BY email_address ASC";

@Bean
@StepScope
JdbcCursorItemReader<StudentDTO> studentsJdbcReader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<StudentDTO> databaseReader = new 
JdbcCursorItemReader<>();

    databaseReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    databaseReader.setSql(QUERY_FIND_STUDENTS);
    databaseReader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>
(StudentDTO.class));

    return databaseReader;
}
```

Writer Bean

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<StudentDTO> studentFlatWriter(){
        return new StudentXmlWriter(OUTPUT_FILE);
    }
```

To create your custom XML writer Class you can take a look into the example provided by Alexey Saenko in his [Spring Batch Tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-batch-tutorial), actually this tutorial will give you a good foundation to understand Spring Batch.